# io.sails.js catch connection refused way

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

My question is about the way to catch socket connection refused.

Im using

```
"sails.io.js": "1.2.1",
"socket.io-client": "2.1.0"
```

According to doc

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket-on

There are only two system events:

```
io.socket.on('connect', function(){});
io.socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Is there some other possibility to catch connection refused?